# How to Sharing Image over other platform

Tags: android, share, android-permissions

i am developing an social image sharing application in android.
which works fine, i want to implement my application like the attachment describes.
i want to know what permission should i use to provide that link in the other application's share/attachment link.

any help will be appreciated, if my code is required i can provide that too.
Thank You!

[image: attachment image file 1]

[image: attachment image file 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you have to declare an activty with IntentFilter "android.action.SEND" in the Manifest file of your app and "mpeg/jpeg" as the mime type.
Then your application will be listed here. 
You'll get the action and URI in the intent.